# How to transform equation

Tags: differential-equations, algebraic-manipulation

Is there any possible way to write this equation of 4th order as a system of two diff equations of second order with two new variables and to do that automatically? statespace command is transforming it into first order

```
  eq=a1*X1[x] + a2*Derivative[2][X1][x]-Derivative[4][X1][x];
```

Comment: This isn't an equation because it doesn't contain an `Equal` sign, only a `=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such manipulations it's sometimes useful to look at the derivatives as if they were powers of a differential operator, and then your expression becomes a polynomial in this operator.

Once you have the polynomial form, it is possible to apply functions such as `Eliminate` to achieve some automation.

First I define the equation to start with (adding an arbitrary righthand side `rhs`), then I replace `Derivative` patterns with appropriate powers of a symbolic operator `dOp`, leading to a new equation `eqPoly`:

```
Clear[X1, Y1]

eq = 
 a1*X1[x] + a2*Derivative[2][X1][x] - Derivative[4][X1][x] == rhs;

eqPoly = eq /. Derivative[n_][X1][x] :> dOp^n

(* ==> a2 dOp^2 - dOp^4 + a1 X1[x] == rhs *)

newEq = Eliminate[{eqPoly, dOp^2 == newOp}, dOp]

(* ==> -rhs + a1 X1[x] == -a2 newOp + newOp^2 *)

newEq /. {newOp^n_ :> Derivative[n][Y1][x], newOp :> Y1[x]}

(* ==> -rhs + a1 X1[x] == -a2 Y1[x] + (Y1^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] *)
```

In `newEq`, I eliminate `dOp` using the second equation which **defines** the operator `newOp` that corresponds to the second derivative of the original function, also considered as an operator whose powers correspond to differentiations. The latter are re-introduced in the last step by replacing `newOp` with `Y1[x]`, the new function, and similarly its derivatives.

The definition `dOp^2 == newOp` of the new function in the `Eliminate` step is equivalent to `Derivative[2][X1][x] == Y1[x]`  in the new notation, which is the second equation of the coupled system.

Comment: in final equation I have -rhs + a1 X1[x] == -a2 Y1[x] + (Y1^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] two variables plus rhs unknowns, how to solve this?

Comment: The problem is how to solve because I have two functions X1[x] and Y1[x] from the output. Firstly I have to solve Y1 and then back to the substitution Derivative[2][X1][x] == Y1[x], but how to solve Y1